# Image classification with tensorflow: Three different methods evaluate the result with same model and same test data but yield different results

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am doing a image classification problem, and it is a binary classification to decide if the picture is good or bad. I have trained a model and when I evaluate the model with test set, I found the classification report is different using 3 methods:

1. Read images one by one and fill it into the model.
2. Generate tf dataset using image_dataset_from_directory
3. Use the evaluate method of the model.

Below is the code:

```
import config as config
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.utils import image_dataset_from_directory
import numpy as np
from keras.models import load_model
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix
from imutils.paths import list_images

TEST_DIR = config.VALIDATION_DIR
IMAGE_HEIGHT = config.IMAGE_HEIGHT
IMAGE_WIDTH = config.IMAGE_WIDTH
BATCH_SIZE = config.BATCH_SIZE
OUTPUT_PATH = config.OUTPUT_PATH
BEST_MODEL_PATH = config.BEST_MODEL_PATH

#model
model = load_model(BEST_MODEL_PATH)

# Read images one by one and fill it into the model.
imagePaths = list(list_images(TEST_DIR))
labels = []
predictions = []
for imagePath in imagePaths:
  img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
    imagePath, target_size=(IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH)
  )
  img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
  img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)  # Create batch axis

  label = imagePath.split('/')[-2]
  if label == 'good':
    label= 1
  else:
    label = 0

  prediction = model.predict(img_array)[0]
  prediction = tf.nn.sigmoid(prediction)
  prediction = tf.where(prediction < 0.5, 0, 1).numpy()
  labels.append(label)
  # print(labels)
  predictions.extend(prediction)

print(classification_report(labels,predictions, target_names=['bad','good']))
print(confusion_matrix(labels,predictions))


#Generate tf dataset using image_dataset_from_directory

test_ds = image_dataset_from_directory(
  TEST_DIR,
  # subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  batch_size=64,
  image_size=(IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH))
class_names = test_ds.class_names
# class_names = test_ds.class_names
images = []
labels = []
for image, label in test_ds.take(-1):
  images.extend(image)
  labels.extend(label)
images = np.array(images)
labels = np.array(labels)
print(images.shape)
print(labels.shape)

predictions = model.predict(images)
predictions = tf.nn.sigmoid(predictions)
predictions = tf.where(predictions < 0.5, 0, 1)

print(classification_report(labels,predictions, target_names=class_names))
print(confusion_matrix(labels,predictions))

#Use the evaluate method of the model.
print(model.evaluate(test_ds))enter code here
```

and the result is showing below:

[image]

accuracy is 0.85,0.87 and 0.86, and the confusion matrix is different too.
Why this happened? I don't know which method should I use to actually evaluate my model.
Hope for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you should use the same preprocessing method  that was used to train your model. If you used tf.keras preprocessing then you should use **tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img**. If you used numpy then your inference script should also use numpy preprocessing.

lets suppose while training you are using the flag **"interpolation=lanczos"** in your **ImageDataGenerator or image_dataset_from_directory** then while inference you should use the same flag i.e **" interpolation=lanczos"** in **tf.keras.preprocessinh.image.load_img** . when you don't mention the interpolation while training, the default interpolation method is used.

Comment: Yeah, but in my example all preprocessing are based on tensorflow, and that is resize the image to (224,224,3). And I include some rescale method in my model.  My model is : **rescale-augmentation-inceptionv3_without_head-Dense(1024)-Dense(2)**. So is it the resize method matters when I use **tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img** and **image_dataset_from_dictionary** ?

Comment: ya, it does matter. lets suppose while training you are using the flag "interpolation=lanczos" in your ImageDataGenerator or image_dataset_from_directory then while inference you should use the same flag i.e " interpolation=lanczos" in tf.keras.preprocessinh.image.load_img . when you don't mention the interpolation while training, the default interpolation method is used.

Comment: Yeah, I think I find the problem. in **image_dataset_from_dictionary** it uses **keras.preprocessing.image_dataset.load_image** function while I use  **tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img** which is different. I just load **keras.preprocessing.image_dataset.load_image** and it goes right!

Comment: why are you using tf.nn.softmax after prediction from the model. I don't think that is necessary

Comment: Because I don't add activation function at the last prediction layer. I write my script based on tf official tutorial and they just leave last layer without activation.